# Regex (negative lookahead)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

```
^(!?\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{13})$
```

This the `regex`, I want to match every `URL` except the ones that have `/something/something/13-character-group`

So if I make:

`/something/something/123456789012` this would match

`/something/something/1234567890123` this would not match

Tnx alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By matching every URL except those having `/something/something/13-character-group`, I'm assuming that your input strings will have characters before and after those you mentioned in your question.

First point to note: a negative lookahead is invoked with `(?! ... )` (and not `!?` because this means 1 `!` character or none). Then, to look for this string anywhere in the URL, you will have to use a `.*` before the pattern and a word boundary after the pattern:

```
^(?!.*/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*/[a-zA-Z0-9]{13}\b).+$
```

The last `.+` is to match the actual URL.

Comment: @Adrian Good luck! You might visit [this site](http://regular-expressions.info) to help you :)

Comment: Another thing to note is that if you only want to test for a match, rather than return the match itself (why would you? you already have the full url you're testing against), you can get rid of the `.+$` at the end.

Comment: @Phylogenesis You're right. Ah well, it doesn't change much, but yes, it can be removed without altering the result.

Answer (score 2):

This should work!

```
var str1 = '/something/something/123456789012';
var str2 = '/something/something/1234567890123';

var re = /^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\/(?![a-zA-Z0-9]{13}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/;

alert(re.test(str1));
alert(re.test(str2));
```

It looks like this.

[image: regex]

Image from [Regexper.com](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: I see a problem with this one. How about `/something/something/12345678901234`?

Comment: Good catch @Birei. I'm fixing it.

Comment: @Adrian did say "everything but the 13 char sequences". How about just change "13" to "13," in the neg. look ahead? In any case, Oskar, why do you escape the forward slashes? I.e. "\/"?

Comment: @h.alex Yes, it's fixed now, update answer to see it. Why I escape forward slashes? Habit.

Comment: @h.alex: He has to escape the slashes because he's using a regex literal, which uses forward slashes as its delimiters.